# How to check if all the radio button gropus in a division are checked or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am weighting a code where user will select their answer for questions they are asked.
There would be multiple questions per page. And I want all those questions to be answered.
Below is the code of the questions form where questions are being called dynamically from database in a loop.

```
<form id="radio-demo" class="radio-demo" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/register-response" method="POST">
    <?php
/* print_r($categories); */

/*loop to get questions for each categories*/
foreach($cat as $categories){       
$software = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."statement where statement_category_id =".$categories->statement_category_id);
$j++;
    $table = $software;
    $c_id = $categories->statement_category_id;     
    $i = 0;

    ?>

     <div class="custom_hide" id="page_<?php echo $j;?>">
     <?php
     $cat_name = $categories->statement_category;
     /*loop for the number of questions per category */
    foreach($table as $software) {
        $i++; 
        ?>


        <div class="question_one">
            <p><?php echo $i.". ".$software->statement;?></p>



              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="first-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 1*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="first-choice">1</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="second-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 2*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="second-choice">2</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="third-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 3*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="third-choice">3</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="four-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 4*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="four-choice">4</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="five-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 5*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="five-choice">5</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="six-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 6*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="six-choice">6</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="seven-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 7*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="seven-choice">7</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="eight-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 8*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="eight-choice">8</label>
              </label>

               <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="nine-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 9*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="nine-choice">9</label>
              </label>

              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="ten-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 10*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="ten-choice">10</label>
              </label>

              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $c_id.'_'.$i;?>" id="eleven-choice-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo 0*$software->weight;?>" required = "required"/> 
                <label for="eleven-choice">No Opinion</label>
              </label>
             <!-- <input type="hidden" name="currentID" value="<?php echo $c_id; ?>" />-->


    </div> <?php }?>
    <div class="bottum_btn">
    <div class="">

        <?php if($j > 1){?>
        <div class="back_btn">
            <a onclick="custom_back(<?php echo $j-1;?>)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left">Back</i> </a>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        if($j == $catcount){?>
        <div class="next_btn">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="submit""><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></input>
        </div>
        <!--<a name="submit"  id="submit_btn" onClick="PopUp()">submit<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
        </a>-->
    <?php } else
    {
        ?>
        <div class="next_btn">
        <a onclick="custom_next(<?php echo $j+1;?>)">Next<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i> </a>
        </div><?php
    }?>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>

<?php }?>
```

The script I am trying is as below.

```
function custom_next(val) {
        var val1 = "#page_" + val;
        var val2 = "#page_" + (val - 1);            
        var questions = jQuery(".question_one");
        var maindiv = jQuery(val2);

        if (jQuery(val2+':not(:has(:radio:checked))').length > 1) {
            console.log(jQuery(val2+':not(:has(:radio:checked))').length);
            alert("At least one group is blank");
        }else{
                console.log(jQuery(val2+':not(:has(:radio:checked))').length);
                jQuery(val1).removeClass("custom_hide");
                jQuery(val1).addClass("custom_show");
                jQuery(val2).removeClass("custom_show");
                jQuery(val2).addClass("custom_hide");
        }}
```

But this script is checking for "**if any of the radio button group is checked or not**" where I want all of the radio button groups to be checked.

Comment: Instead of using `id`, try using `name selector` for all distinct names. `$("[name='inputName']").is(":checked")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have analyzed your code and I have developed this code for your script. This scripts checks if any of your question options is checked or not.

```
function custom_next(val) {
        var val1 = "#page_" + val;
        var val2 = "#page_" + (val - 1);        
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        jQuery('div.custom_show input[type=radio]').each(function(){                            
            var status = jQuery(this).is(':checked');
            //alert(status);
            i=i+1;
            if(status == true){
                j=j+1;
            }               
        });         
        i= i/11;
        if(i == j){
            jQuery(val1).removeClass("custom_hide");
                jQuery(val1).addClass("custom_show");
                jQuery(val2).removeClass("custom_show");
                jQuery(val2).addClass("custom_hide");
        }else{
            alert("All Questions are mandetory!!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this script is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

First find all the radio button groups inside your form

```
var radio_groups = [];
$("#radio-demo :radio").each(function(){
    radio_groups.push(this.name);
});
```

Now iterate through all of them to see if any one is not selected

```
var isAnyUnselected = radio_groups.filter( function(vallue){

  return $(":radio[name='"+group+"']:checked").length == 0

} ).length > 0;
```

check if `isAnyUnselected` is `true` (some are unselected) or `false` (all of them are selected)

Comment: what **#radio-demo** is for in this code? Is it the id for the division that contains all the radio button groups? @gurvinder372

Comment: @VijayPatel radio-demo is the id of your form. Yes this contains all the radio button groups

Answer (score 0):

> But this script is checking for "if any of the radio button group is checked or not" where I want all of the radio button groups to be checked.

What you need to do is check if there is at least one radio box that is not checked. Small example:

```
<input class="ans" type="radio"/>
<input class="ans" type="radio"/>

if ($('.ans').not(':checked').length)
{
    console.log('At least one not checked, please check all');
}
else
{
    console.log('All checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to change the html you can use the selector `jQuery("input[type='radio']:not(:checked)")` if the `.length` of this selector is greater than 1 there are some input to check. Simple example **[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6JGQbiReJgQis2WfsfXl?p=preview)** se the console logs.

Otherwise you could use the **required** attribute **[link1](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/html/using-html-required-attribute/)** **[link2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate)**.